# Framer Code Overide: How to swap component varient?

Tags: javascript, typescript, framer-motion

I'm trying to swap out a component variant by clicking on a button (a separate component).

I managed to cycle through and swap variants but I'm stuck on how I swap a specific variant only. The following is a code override in Framer which gets applied to a button - how would I adapt so only the Quarterly item in the array is chosen?

```
import type { ComponentType } from "react"
import { createStore } from "https://framer.com/m/framer/store.js@^1.0.0"

const useStore = createStore({
    variant: "Monthly",
})

export function withComponent(Component): ComponentType {
    return (props) => {
        const [store, setStore] = useStore()

        return <Component {...props} variant={store.variant} />
    }
}

export function withButton(Component): ComponentType {
    return (props) => {
        const [store, setStore] = useStore()

        // Add an array with all the variants
        const variants = ["Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly"]

        const getNextVariant = (currentVariant) => {
            const currentIndex = variants.indexOf(currentVariant)
            const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % variants.length
            return variants[nextIndex]
        }

        return (
            <Component
                {...props}
                onClick={(e) =>
                    setStore({
                        ...store,
                        variant: getNextVariant(store.variant),
                    })
                }
            />
        )
    }
}
```